# How do I bind the rows in my Datagrid to properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, binding, properties

This is the code in my viewmodel:

```
public DataView VariationGrid
{
    get
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();

        #region Columns
        foreach (var param in SelQuestion.QuestionParameters)
        {
            DataColumn datac = new DataColumn(param.Name);
            data.Columns.Add(datac);
        } 
        #endregion

        #region Rows
        foreach (Variation variation in SelQuestion.Variations)
        {
            DataRow datarow = data.NewRow();
            foreach (var parameter in variation.QuestionParameters)
            {
                datarow[parameter.Key.Name] = parameter.Value;
            }
            data.Rows.Add(datarow);
        } 
        #endregion

        return data.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

This I bind to the `ItemsSource` of my DataGrid.

Now I want to edit a cell, but how do I notify this to my property that his value has changed?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to do binding because you are creating the object/collection locally and then lose track of it. This is very bad practice because on each get the collection will be recreated.

Load the data once (into an instance field/property).